# Prevent rendering of TYPO3 default heading of FCE

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

In FCE I dont want to use default TYPO3 elements like header, link etc. So I hide it with  the following ts config:

```
    TCEFORM.tt_content {
    header.types.templavoila_pi1.disabled = 1
    header_position.types.templavoila_pi1.disabled = 1
    header_link.types.templavoila_pi1.disabled = 1
    header_layout.types.templavoila_pi1.disabled = 1
    date.types.templavoila_pi1.disabled = 1
    subheader.types.templavoila_pi1.disabled = 1
    }
```

After this unwanted fields are not shown. But when I save and close the content in backend, title part of the page content shows [No title].

Here is the screen short of page content:

[image]

So I desided to keep default heading field by removing the line:

```
header.types.templavoila_pi1.disabled = 1
```

from the tsconfig. How to prevent rendering of heading field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mark it as hidden.** Edit your content (CASE#1) and from Type choose the last one named hidden.

[image]

or overwrite the header css config and set it to

```
display:none;
```

Comment: can I set display:none; only to FCE

Comment: or can I  set type to hidden by default?

Comment: No, you have to set it in each content where you want to hide header. Try to set display none via css, it will be applied to all headers

Comment: But if I set display none via css it will effect every content element. I just want to hide header's of FCE only.

Answer (score 0):

My backend template for my base template includes backend styling for the headline [no title]

```
<style>
.sortable_handle {
    color: transparent;
}
.tpm-title-cell {
    display: none;
}
</style>
###content###
```

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3v7 and v8, you can influence the content preview header by registering a hook for

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem']
```

and resetting the `$headerContent` variable in your hook.

See https://stmllr.net/blog/customizing-preview-widgets-in-the-typo3-page-module/